# $\liminf_{|x|\to \infty} |x f(x)| =0$ for a Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Having trouble proving something I saw on an old qualifying exam. It goes as follows, let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function such that
$$ \int f(x)  \: \textrm{d}x < \infty ,  $$
then 
$$ \liminf_{|x| \to \infty } |x f(x) | = 0$$
I am not sure how to proceed as I have not seen anything of this form before, well there is a nice analogue in the Riemann case dealing with limits, I am sure what properties of Lebesgue integrable function to use in this case. Thanks.

Comment: If the $\liminf$ is not zero, then what can you say about $|f|$ and its integrability?

Comment: Personally, not too much at this point. Hence the question, note that it is clear that $\liminf |f| =0$, but we  are interested in $\liminf |x f(x) |$.

Comment: You need $|f|$ in the first integral.

Comment: They are equivalent with regards to Lebesgue integrability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\liminf_x |xf(x)| >0$ then there is some $L$, $\delta>0$ such that
for $|x| \ge L$ we have
$|xf(x)| \ge \delta$.

Then $|f(x)| \ge {\delta \over |x|}$ for $|x| \ge L$ and hence
$f$ is not integrable.